# vba Byref argument type mismatch when calling the function

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a method to rename the table column name.

```
Public Function Rename_Column(tablename As String, oldcolumn As String, newcolumn As String)
  Dim dbs As Database, tdf As TableDef
  Set dbs = CurrentDb

  For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name = tablename Then
      For Each fld In tdf.Fields
        If fld.Name = oldcolumn Then
          fld.Name = newcolumn
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next
  dbs.Close
End Function
```

And i'm calling this function in other procedure

```
Public Sub querylistboxitems()
  Dim strTableName As String

  strTableName = "Table1"
  Call Rename_Column(strTableName, "old", "New")
End Sub
```

But it is giving an error "Byref argument type mismatch"

Comment: On what line?  The VBE should hilight the line with the mismatch... it looks like the call is set up properly to me.  You have 3 strings so you should be ok there...

Comment: It is hilighting **strTableName** in **querylistboxitems** procedure

Comment: Try Throwing ByVal infront of your variable declarations in your function, I have had this work for me before

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine for me. There is some other problem, for example, strTableName is defined elsewhere. Try a compile and make sure you use Option Explicit. You could make this a lot quicker with very little work.

Comment: @swa1234 always use option explicit. I see no reason why the error would be occurring. Are you certain everything in your code is typed as you typed it above?  Also, you may just want to use another sub instead of a function for the Rename_Column function if you aren't returning a value.

Comment: Thank you all for your time. In my original code i quoted the line by mistake,**Dim strTableName As String**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It failed for me because you did not define "fld".  The following is a lot more direct than looping thru all tables / fields:

```
Public Function Rename_Column(tablename As String, oldcolumn As String, newcolumn As String)
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim tdf As TableDef
    Dim fld As Field

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set tdf = dbs.TableDefs(tablename)
    Set fld = tdf.Fields(oldcolumn)
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    dbs.Close
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 22):

There are other tricky situations where this problem may occur. For example when declaring two (or more)  variables on one line:

```
Dim firstSubMenu, secondSubMenu As CommandBarPopup
```

Now firstSubMenu is of type Variant, while secondSubMenu is of type CommandBarPopup. This may not be what you intended and can also be a cause for the above mentioned error when passing them by reference to a function that expects a parameter of type CommandBarPopup.
In this case a solution is to declare them on two lines:

```
Dim firstSubMenu As CommandBarPopup
Dim secondSubMenu As CommandBarPopup
```

Or, if you really want to squeeze it on one line, it can be done like this:

```
Dim firstSubMenu As CommandBarPopup, secondSubMenu As CommandBarPopup
```

Note that you'll have to repeat the 'As' type declaration for each variable.

Comment: Has anyone found another way to solve this error?

It can be quite annoying if you have a lot of different variables that your are passing into the function.

Comment: I have added the unexpected behaviour of `Dim string1, string2, string3 As String` to my list of "Excel VBA WTF's." +1 and thanks.